# How do I load test my http server on azure without getting IP banned automatically

Tags: azure, load-testing

I have an Ubuntu Server VM running on Microsoft Azure and I need to do some custom load testing. I've written a Python script that makes the necessary requests. The issue is that I know Azure will block my IP automatically if I send too many requests per second. I don't know what this threshold is though. I'd like to send as many requests per second as my local network and hardware will allow. I definitely don't want to have to open a support ticket to get myself unbanned from connecting to the server though.

As far as I can tell everything inside of the VM is configured so that I won't get blocked.

Comment: It's likely to be quite a high threshold - higher than one computer can manage to generate - but it might be wise to reach out to Azure Support to give them a heads-up that you're doing a test.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect that you are very much correct. I just went ahead and sent about 70 requests per second and didn't get banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like to be an [Azure feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-protection-overview)

> Every property in Azure is protected by Azure's infrastructure DDoS (Basic) Protection at no additional cost.

It should be possible to [turn DDoS protection off](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/manage-ddos-protection)

> To disable DDoS protection for a virtual network:
>
> 1.Enter the name of the virtual network you want to disable DDoS protection standard for in the Search resources, services, and docs box at the top of the portal. When the name of the virtual network appears in the search results, select it.
> 2. Select Under DDoS Protection Standard, select Disable.
>
> If you want to delete a DDoS protection plan, you must first dissociate all virtual networks from it.

Alternatively you can run your tests from another Azure VM, the traffic will be considered "internal" and you won't be limited by your local NIC/ISP bandwidth.

And last but not the least, you can consider switching to a load testing tool which provides [IP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) capabilities (or amend your script so each thread would bind to its own IP address or alias), one of possible options is [Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/)

Comment: This is not entirely correct. There are two tiers of DDoS protection, basic and standard. Standard is an additional cost and can be turned on or off, but basic is applied to all resources and cannot be disabled.